# Can't test validation error-message element using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to write e2e test for login, but i have problem with checking this error message, tried many css locators different ways but it never worked.

Screenshot:
[image: error message]

Error message:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="validation"])

It seems that error message wont show when e2e test is running in chrome.

My code:

```js
//login.po.ts

validationMessage() {
        return element(by.id('validation'));
    }

//login.e2e-spec.ts

 it('should not login with wrong email and password', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        page.inputLogin().sendKeys(fakeLogin);
        expect(page.buttonSubmit().isEnabled()).toBe(false);
        page.inputPassword().sendKeys(fakePass);
        expect(page.buttonSubmit().isEnabled()).toBe(true);
        page.buttonSubmit().click().then(() => {
             browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(page.validationMessage()), 5000); //If the error span takes time to be visible, use wait() function
             expect(page.validationMessage().getText()).toEqual('User not found');
        });
```

My HTML code:

```html
<div *ngIf="!submitted">
    <h1 class="inner-main-title">Login</h1>
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="signinForm">
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="E-Mail" formControlName="email" type="email" required/>
        </md-input-container>
        <app-control-messages [control]="signinForm.controls.email"></app-control-messages>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" type="password"/>
        </md-input-container>
        <div *ngIf="formErrors" class="validation-message">
            <h3 class="error-message" [innerHTML]="formErrors" id="validation"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="link"><a routerLink="./account-recovery">Forgot password?</a></div>
        <button id="login-button" class="cta-green" type="submit" md-raised-button [disabled]="!signinForm.valid"
                color="primary">login
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="submitted">
    <h1 class="inner-main-title">Please wait...</h1>
    <md-spinner></md-spinner>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

already solved it.

Problem was in protractor that it didnt wait for page to fully load.

browser.waitForAngular(); just wait for page to redirect not fully load its content. Adding browser.sleep(1000) solved problem. Different situations require much longer wait time.

Here is working code:

```
it('should not login with wrong password', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    page.inputLogin().sendKeys(fakeLogin);
    expect(page.buttonSubmit().isEnabled()).toBe(false);
    page.inputPassword().sendKeys(fakePass);
    expect(page.buttonSubmit().isEnabled()).toBe(true);
    page.buttonSubmit().click().then(() => {
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.sleep(1000);
        expect(page.validationMessage().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
```

Hope it helps someone else.